# unauthorized API key with Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I registered a new application in google developer console and created a new server key. However, posting to https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send returns 401:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=$api_key" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"APA91bEjNEnC2uKJhzjAGFupsvMp59DL67HIow5RO4eeinRV5eR1uiIIlEmJw8C_jzL18MyxYmsNJbam-M03xKopCfWqpTq0rkM93CRvRVx_h2tbyAfZfOvZc5NTAOjspWeXDJGlazHug7qXb4Tgg059ZXq-MHxwDA\"]}"
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Does anyone know what might go wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check two things:

1. You are defining `$api_key` with the full server key.
2. You enabled the "Google Cloud Messaging for Android" API in the Google Developers Console.